# Created in the Divine Image

Tags: theology, creation, adam, genesis-bereishith

The Torah tells us that Adam was created in the divine image (Gen 1.26-27; 5; 9.6). If the divinity had a body, then we would suppose this means that Adam was created as the divinity's Doppelgänger, but a corporal deity is foreign to both tradition and reason so the Torah must have something else in mind. I have seen several interpretation of Adam's divine image, but perhaps someone might be so kind as to summarize the major opinions in a convenient list for the enlightenment of all.

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org.il/Nefesh_HaChayim%2C_Gate_I.1?lang=bi

Comment: @JoelK Chaim of Volozhin appears to take the contextual approach adopted by earlier authorities like Saadia Gaon that see "divine image" as a reference to Adam's dominion over much of Creation. This is contextual because in Genesis 1, the image is immediately followed by the Creator describing Adam as the ruler of terrestrial realm.

Comment: Yair Lorberbaum,  https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9781107477940 discusses rabbinic sources relating to this question.

Comment: Jacob Jervell https://archive.org/details/imagodeigen126fi0000jerv discusses "Late Jewish" (meaning post-biblical) sources on the question.

Answer (score 2):

I have seen the following interpretations:

1. Superior intellect ([Philo](https://el.wikisource.org/wiki/%CE%A0%CE%B5%CF%81%CE%AF_%CF%84%CE%B7%CF%82_%CE%BA%CE%B1%CF%84%CE%AC_%CE%9C%CF%89%CF%85%CF%83%CE%AD%CE%B1_%CE%BA%CE%BF%CF%83%CE%BC%CE%BF%CF%80%CE%BF%CE%B9%CE%AF%CE%B1%CF%82) and [Maimonides](https://mechon-mamre.org/i/1104.htm))
2. Immortality ([Book of Wisdom](https://www.academic-bible.com/en/online-bibles/septuagint-lxx/read-the-bible-text/bibel/text/lesen/stelle/41/20001/29999/ch/687a3596e8b9fe702a57527279a01c0a/))
3. Chosen by the creator for special dignity ([Saadia Gaon](https://vf.genizah.org/JA/Images/Rasag/Bereshit.P/H053ja.png))
4. Dominion over the earth and all its inhabitants ([Saadia Gaon](https://vf.genizah.org/JA/Images/Rasag/Bereshit.P/H053ja.png))
5. ֹAngels and other divine beings appear like noble humans to the prophets as humans are the closest things to angels imaginable ([Judah Halevi](https://vf.genizah.org/JA/Images/Rihal/Cuzari/H157ja.png))
6. Free will ([Jacob ben Wolf Kranz](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40245&st=&pgnum=153))

Comment: Free will?.....

Comment: There are much earlier sources which say divine image = free will, I believe.

Comment: For example, the [Seforno](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.1.26?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Sforno_on_Genesis.1.26.4&lang2=bi)?

Comment: In the link I provided he discusses free will

Comment: Some claim that Judah Loew ben Bezalel defines the divine image as free will, but in fact he says this is a consequence of the image rather the essence of the image. See  https://www.sefaria.org/Derekh_Chayim.3.15.3?vhe=Derech_Chaim,_with_footnotes_and_annotations_by_Rabbi_Yehoshua_D._Hartman,_Machon_Yerushalyim,_2005-2010&lang=he&with=all&lang2=he

Comment: To clarify, Obadiah Sforno distinguishes between the divine image (צלם) and the divine likeness (דמות), the former representing intellect and immortality and the latter representing free will.